# Mysql query to efficiently migrate a column to foreign key

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to separate a lot of duplicate text strings from one table into another, so that I convert to a foreign-key system instead.

Pulling the unique text and inserting into the new table is easy, but I tried the following update/subquery to update the original table with the new foreign key values. On 22 million rows, it took longer than I would like.

Any way I can make this more efficient? I doubt doing a subquery is a good solution. The original table has a `player` col with strings of player names. I've dumped all unique values to a separate table, and want to update the original table with the new IDs.

```
UPDATE prism_actions SET player_id = (SELECT prism_players.id FROM prism_players WHERE prism_players.player = prism_actions.player);
Query OK, 22018608 rows affected (2 hours 21 min 58.97 sec)
```

I had used an example several years ago to do this but for the life me, nothing I search for gives me anything remotely related to what I'm trying to do. Google just can't figure out what I mean, and I can't think of any more ways to ask.

Comment: for 22M rows i think the time is fine. also mind if you are using myisam it locks the table or engine when you are updating. that may be bottleneck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a simple:

UPDATE prism_actions a, prism_players p SET a.player_id = p.player_id where a.player=p.player;

I don't know how much quicker, but it would eliminate the subquery.

Comment: Doesn't seem too much faster but it's certainly cleaner. Thanks!